# ResponsiveVoice.js - Getting Around iOS TTS Required Direct User Interaction

Tags: javascript, ios, onload, responsivevoice

On the [ResponsiveVoice.JS website](http://responsivevoice.org/) under the quirks section it states:

> iOS TTS can’t be triggered without a direct user interaction, ResponsiveVoice JS resolves this

But, for the life of me, I can't get around this direct user interaction requirement. **How do you get around this?**

Here is the code snippet I'm trying to execute without user interaction I currently have located in the `<head>` element:

```
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function speak_static_data(){
        responsiveVoice.speak('Test');
    } 
    setTimeout(function(){ speak_static_data(); }, 3000);
</script>
```

I would like to call `responsiveVoice.speak('Test');` on page load in iOS without direct user interaction. How would I do this?

This same code snippet speaks fine on Android/Safari on desktop/Chrome on desktop but not in iOS.

Answer (score 5):

So I was searching around for this and hidden in their FAQs they have iOS Guidelines. They don't fully circumvent it, but instead get around it ever time after the first instance.

> On iOS, some events such as Speech Synthesis, need to be triggered from a user action (i.e. a click). That causes ResponsiveVoice speak calls not to work on page load, for example.
>
> With Speech Synthesis, that user triggered action only needs to be done once. Further direct calls after the first one will work as expected.
>
> So, the recommended best practice is to add a “Start” button to the experience for the user to click, and use that as a initialization call to responsiveVoice.speak(). That call, if desired, can have a blank space as text, so there’s no impact to the user.

You don't need to actually have anything said, so having a button that the user just clicks that calls responsiveVoice is enough.

```
<button onclick="responsiveVoice.speak('');">Enable Voice</button>
```

Responsve Voice FAQ: https://responsivevoice.org/faq/